# TriggerDagRunOperator 2x on Same Dag with different conf

Tags: airflow

I am trying to trigger a dag 2 times within a for loop using `TriggerDagRunOperator` but with a different `conf` -- ie each dag run has different parameters to run against. I also have `reset_dag_run=True` to be able to retry the same dag run if there is a failure; I also have the same execution date (`{{ ts }}`)set; and set the `trigger_run_id` based on different uuids

However, I noticed none of these lead to a second dag run getting triggered. Only one gets triggered. I can find the dag run associated with the `dag_run_id` and `ts` of one of the Triggers, but not the other.

What is the issue here? How can I get around this?

Comment: please share your code

Comment: A DAG is just a configuration, if you need to pass other parameters, just design a new DAG with these.